# Custom image name in php

Tags: php, image

Is there anyway to create custom image name? I was trying this code, but it didn't work (it only uploads photo and renames it in database, which causes to not display an image)

```
<label>Photo</label>
<input type="file" name="prd_img" value="<?php echo $prd_img; ?>">
<label>Photo name</label>
<input type="text" name="prd_img" value="<?php echo $prd_img; ?>">
```

PHP:

```
  <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['prd_cat']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['prd_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['prd_price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['prd_desc']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<img width="100" src="/images/' . $row['prd_img'] 
  . '" />'; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['prd_id']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="server.php?del=<?php echo $row['prd_id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add your PHP to the question.

Comment: Thanks. Just did it

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: I want to give a custom name for my image. For example it was uploaded as 123.jpg and I want to give name 321.jpg to it

Comment: That'll be in the actual "upload" part of your PHP code, add that to your question.

Comment: But the second label changes the name, but It forces to not display an image

Comment: Your second input has the same name as the file being upload, you'll probably find that somewhere along the way it has changed the db entry for the file to the `321.jpg` but the actual file is still called `123.jpg` hence why it's not showing. Best way to fix this is to change the name of the custom name input to something else and change the name you save the photo as in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `move_uploaded_file` and setting the name after the file is uploaded.

Upload the image file along with a form text field having the custom name.

Capture both the values in php and store it in the server with the custom name.

Have a look at the example below for more clarity.

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Photo</label>
    <input type="file" name="prd_img">
    <label>Photo name</label>
    <input type="text" name="prd_img_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
$newfilename = $_POST["prd_img_name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["prd_img"]["name"], "../img/path/" . $newfilename);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
But I'm failing as hell anyway...
Notice: Undefined index: prd_img_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_area\index.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: prd_img in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_area\index.php on line 28

Comment: Did you add the HTML part of it to your form? From the error you have shared, it is clearly seen that both `prd_img` and `prd_img_name` are not added to the form or you have named them differently in your form. Can you share the updated code?

Comment: I did upload it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03aaa214f86d6ba6d0173e1db15d1b6c71276dc0

Comment: @Lahante did you figure it out or you still need help on this ?